# How to access client secret file of google calendar

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

I want to access client_secret file of google calendar and to use it to add an event in my calendar.

I'm creating a chatbot in c# and in the moment that I use the path of my computer ( when I try to access client_secret file of my project in my pc ) works goods.

When I publish the project on the web and try to access the file I can't.

My code is :

```
 string path =  @"C:\Project\Test\Bot\V3\client_secret.json";

 string pathi = @"{
 'installed': {
'client_id': '1111111- 
  21432423.apps.googleusercontent.com',
'project_id': '111',
'auth_uri': 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
'token_uri': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
'auth_provider_x509_cert_url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
'client_secret': '22222222222222',
'redirect_uris': [ 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', 'http:dev.ai.com/BotTest/' ]
      }
  }";


            UserCredential credential;
            string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
               System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            using (var stream =
           new FileStream(pathi, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
               Scopes,
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None,
               new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            Event newEvent = new Event()
            {

                Summary = "Event",
                Location = "",
                Description = "Event is scheduled for:  " + 
        eventi.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "  " + 
       eventi.Time.ToShortTimeString(),
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {

                    // DateTime = eventi.Date,
                    DateTime = new DateTime(eventi.Date.Year, 
         eventi.Date.Month, eventi.Date.Day, eventi.Time.Hour, 
            eventi.Time.Minute, 0),
                    TimeZone = "Europe/Brussels",


                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {

                    DateTime = eventi.Date.AddMinutes(60),
                    // DateTime = new DateTime(eventi.Date.Year, 
                 eventi.Date.Month, eventi.Date.Day, eventi.Time.Hour, 
                        eventi.Time.Hour +1 ,0),
                    TimeZone = "Europe/Brussels",
                },
                Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1" },
                Attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                new EventAttendee() { Email = "eeee@gmail.com" },

            },

                ///////////////////////////////////////////



                ///////////////////////////////////////////

                Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
                {
                    UseDefault = false,
                    Overrides = new EventReminder[] {
                    new EventReminder() { Method = "email", Minutes = 1 * 60 },
                    new EventReminder() { Method = "sms", Minutes = 10 },
                }
                }
            };
            String calendarId = "primary";
            EventsResource.InsertRequest request1 = 
          service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId);
            Event createdEvent = request1.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Event created: {0}", createdEvent.HtmlLink);

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = eventi.Time;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;


            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            //Console.Read();
            //   context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
    }
```

When i use path   and in this part of code i put path work  :

```
    using (var stream =
           new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
               Scopes,
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None,
               new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

When I put the root of the file in the web doesn't work, the same when i put all the script of the file in a string path :

```
string path = @"http://dev.aaaa.com/bot/client_secret.json"
```

I try to put just the name file but still don't work:

```
 using (var stream =
           new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
               Scopes,
               "user",
               CancellationToken.None,
               new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

Can you help me please how to access this file?

Comment: Please make sure client id & secret defined for the domain "dev.aaaa.com" (generally while development we give localhost, but you may have to change to the actual domain i.e "dev.aaaa.com")matches with the one mentioned in the "client_secret.json' file.Also place client_secret.json at the root and just mention file name as new FileStream requires local file path only!

Comment: Yes i put the correct domain , and still doesn't work . I've got this message : " path cannot be empty string"  in fact when i debug path return the file name path ( so it's not empty " :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy credentials.json to bin\debug and bin\release folders and follow this way if your client is console application ,

```
UserCredential credential;
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
               System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                   new[] { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(credPath));
            }
```

For web App the client_secret.json would look like this and contains redirect uri's etc.

```
{"web":{"client_id":" ","project_id":" ","auth_uri":" ","token_uri":" ","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":" ","client_secret":" ","redirect_uris":[]}}
```

Also don't disclose any of your id's and secrets.

Comment: thnx ...in credentials.json is correct or i have to update with  client_secret.json

Comment: i've got this error : System.ArgumentException: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace.
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore..ctor(String folder, Boolean fullPath) .   In fact path exist and path return client_secret.json file

Comment: Your access token will be saved at  folder parameter of FileDataStore() and after this, do see google authentication screen and after login you should also see consent screen which you have to allow.

Comment: please can you help me with a sample code ...i think that my code work only for desktop app , but in web i have to use smth else :(

Comment: it's necessary to do any change in iis??? because is very bizarre that i can access google caledar when i test in my local pc and when in deploy in web i can't